# STM32F103 NRF24L01 communication problem

Tags: stm32, communication, stm32cubemx, keil, nrf24l01

I am trying to apply communication between two STM32F103C8T6 with NRF24L01 modules. I am using a UART with USB to TTL module to reach a PuTTY terminal. I am using KEIL and CUBEMX for generating code. Here is my while loop:

```
uint8_t CTR_RXBUFF[32];
while (1) {
  if (CTR_nrfGetPacket(CTR_RXBUFF)==1) {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    printf("Received package: ");
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, CTR_RXBUFF, 32,1000);
    memset(CTR_RXBUFF,0x00,32);
    CTR_nrfSetRX();
  } else {
    printf("Cannot get any package \r\n");
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
  HAL_Delay(1000);
}
```

Now here I tried to connect the STM32 without the NRF24 and the PuTTY terminal says:

***"Received package: (some nonsense symbols)"***

And if I try it with the NRF24 connected then the PuTTY terminal says:

***"Cannot get any package"***

[I took the code from here](https://github.com/bluetechsky/stm32f103c8t6-nrf24l01).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

NRF24L01 has a lot of clone (or fake) chips. [by default, protocols are incompatible between genuine and some clone chips and packet exchange is not done correctly](https://forum.mysensors.org/topic/1153/we-are-mostly-using-fake-nrf24l01-s-but-worse-fakes-are-emerging).

if SPI communication was fine but you couldn't get any packets, maybe you have different chips.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved the problem. It was because the NRF module. I bought nrf24l01+ and it solved the problem. And I think the reason of **"Received package: (some nonsense symbols)"** is that MISO pin is trying to get some value but since it is not connected anywhere this happens.

Comment: There ia actually difference in registers between 01 qnd 01+ module.